# TCA file, checkbox default checked

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I would like to set a checkbox in the backend to default checked.

In my case it is the field `showinpreview` in the file `/typo3conf/ext/news/Configuration/TCA/tx_news_domain_model_media.php`.

I changed the value `default` to 1, but it has no effect:

```
'showinpreview' => [
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => $ll . 'tx_news_domain_model_media.showinpreview',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'check',
                'default' => 1
            ]
        ],
```

When I check the TCA File of tt_content for a checked checkbox it looks like this:

```
'sectionIndex' => [
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:sectionIndex',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'check',
        'default' => 1,
        'items' => [
            '1' => [
                '0' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_core.xlf:labels.enabled'
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
```

The only difference I see is the `items`. But I do not really understand what this item-value does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the field `showinpreview` is set in `news/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_file_reference.php`. Apply your change there, and you will be happy.

But be aware: after updating of the news extension your change will be lost.

Comment: Oh wow I totaly missed that. Thanks. (I checked the original sys_file_reference for this field). Would it also be possible to set the default for `sys_language_uid` to `-1` in this file? It says $**new**SysFileReferenceColumns, so I guess I can not just copy the `sys_language_uid` from the original and change the default here?

Comment: Don't change the original extension code. As mentioned the changes will be lost after extension update.

Comment: This is definitely not **not** the best answer. Never change the code if it is not your own. You´ll lose the possibility to update without your changes getting lost. I would also strongly recommend to use @minifranske 's approach and go for PageTSconfig.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to change this value is by overriding TCA with some pageTS. Add following to the pagets of the folder that holds the news records.

`TCAdefaults.sys_file_reference.showinpreview = 1`

See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TCEform/Index.html

For the older EXT:news versions use: `TCAdefaults.tx_news_domain_model_media.showinpreview = 1`

Comment: Oh thats nice to know! Any way I can use this in "normal" Typoscript setup(file) or extTables of my template rather then use it in the pageTS for every page with news on it?

Comment: You can include default page TS in your site package extension. This way, you can avoid including it into every page.

Answer (score 1):

Just checked - this works for me

```
'checkbox' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'My Label',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'check',
            'default' => '1'
        )
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks, I checked it somewhere else now too. Looks like its a specific problem for the field showinpreview of the news Media file.